# How do you breed a Quicksilver Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I've seen reports that there is a new metal hybrid dragon called a Quicksilver Dragon. What is the best dragon breeding combination to get this dragon, and how will I know I was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To breed a [Quicksilver Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Dragon) all you need is to try and breed a **Metal Dragon with a Water Dragon**. Note that you might also get a Rust Dragon. It's breeding/egg time is 18 hours. If your breeding time is 6 hours, you got a Rust Dragon instead.

Note Water/Metal hybrids also work when breeding, but hybrids have a munch lower chance of getting you a Quicksilver since they can result in other combinations.

Comment: I like to prefer Quicksilver dragons as **"bad luck dragons"** when trying to breed a Diamond Dragon, since the combo is mine and ice and they have metal and water. I hate them :/